# Name for the invariant $f(x+c, y+c) = f(x,y)$?

Tags: terminology, functional-equations, invariance

Suppose you have a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^m$ with the property that for any constant $c$, you can add that constant to all of the arguments without changing the value of the function.

Formally, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $c\in \mathbb{R}$,

$$f(x_1,\ldots, x_m) = f(x_1+c,\;\ldots,\;x_m+c).$$

Is there a name for this kind of “translation” invariance?

Comment: mostly called singly periodic, to emphasize that there is just one direction involved. It would be the same if there were a constant $c_i$ for each $x_i;$ as long as you are adding a constant vector

Comment: I'd call it invariant with respect to $(x_1,\dots,x_m)\to(x_1+c,\dots,x_m+c),$ for all $c$.  Or say $f$ depends only on $x_2-x_1,x_3-x_1,\dots,x_m-x_1)$.

Comment: Yes, it's called “translation invariance”! (In the $(1,1,\dots,1)$ direction.)

Comment: @HansLundmark I wasn't sure about calling it translation invariance, since in other contexts (e.g. when talking about Lebesgue measure) it seems to require invariance to adding anything to any argument.  Do you think translation invariance "in a direction" will be intuitively clear as a term?

Comment: At least to me, it would be perfectly clear.

Comment: I'd call it periodic. Translation invariant is also good, but more confusing as user326210 notes (it suggests you could add say $c/2$ to $x_i$ and have it unchanged).